# Receiving Script 70 error in ie11 every time i try to trigger a change event

Tags: html, excel, vba, triggers

```
 Dim htl As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
```

'Start IE object

```
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

'Go to Webpage

```
  IE.Navigate VendorHome
```

'Sub that waits for the page to load

```
Call Load
```

'Create Event

```
      Set htl = IE.document.createEvent("HTMLevents")
      htl.initEvent "change", False, True
```

'Select the Dropdown box

```
SelectOpt.Click
```

'Select Option in Dropdown

```
For Each opt In SelectOpt
     If opt.Text = "Purchase order number" Then
     SelectOpt.ChildNodes(3).Selected = True
      SelectOpt.Options(1).Selected = True
        SelectOpt.selectedIndex = 1
           ' SelectOpt.dispatchEvent (htl) ' Error is Received on this Line 
     End If
 Next
```

Comment: welcome to SO, you did not mention what's the error

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around `htl` on the line which gives the error

Comment: Can you share the HTML/URL as there may be a better way.

Comment: The error I am receiving is SCRIPT70 - Permission Denied. I am unable to share the URL because this is for work.

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried it without the parentheses, it still did not trigger the change event. Any more suggestions?

Comment: What about `SelectOpt.FireEvent("onchange") ` ?

Comment: I tried that as well. Unfortunately didnt work. Any other recommendations